# Where or How can I find a Complete List of Available Services for DNN and 2sxc

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I've been trying to both convert old code and write new code using GetScopedService().

However, I keep discovering ones I didn't know about.

Is there an easy way to find the complete list of services available for 2sxc? For DNN? And maybe even RazorBlade?

If they are not documented somewhere, is there a page of code in the public repositories that I could bookmark where it would be easy to see (and compile) a list of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best place to start is https://r.2sxc.org/services (which goes to https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Services.html)

This is where we keep all the current services published. Other services are to be seen as exotic / rare use.

Razor-Blade is still mostly non-service, but we plan to fix that.

We're just about to release `ServiceKits` as a feature, which would make things even more intuitive. For example, [ServiceKit14](https://docs.2sxc.org/api/dot-net/ToSic.Sxc.Services.ServiceKit14.html) has all commonly used services on it, and also `IScrub` from Razor Blade.